# Not able to send bootstrap form from view to controller after bootstrap validations

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

Scenario

> I have a bootstrap form built in codeigniter on which bootstrap
>   validation has been applied. And i wish that after the validation are
>   fulfilled the user can click on submit button and goes to the action
>   page(i.e controller).

Issue:

> Submit button is not working, due to which the form is not getting
>   redirected

Goal:

> Make the validation work and then redirect the form to the controller so that > value of the form can be saved in database

NOTE

> Here is the [link](https://codepen.io/jaycbrf/pen/iBszr) of a sample code that i have, the only
>   difference between the two is that the question that i am asking is in
>   codeigniter and the link is without codeigniter. However i need the
>   answer for codeigniter:

Code

```
<?php
$reg_attributes = array('id'=>'contact_form','class'=>'form-horizontal');
echo form_open('home/registeruser', $reg_attributes); ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?php
        $data = array(
            'type'=>'text', 
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'name'=>'fullname', 
            'autocomplete'=>'off',
            'placeholder'=>'Full Name',
            'id'=>'user_name'
            );
        ?>

    <?php echo form_input($data); ?>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <?php
        $data = array(
            'type'=>'submit',
            'class'=>'btn btn-success btn-block',
            'name'=>'submit',
            'content'=>'Register',
            'value'=>'submit',
        );

        echo form_button($data); 
    ?>
</div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#contact_form').bootstrapValidator({
            feedbackIcons: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                fullname: {
                    validators: {
                            stringLength: {
                            min: 2,
                        },
                            notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Please supply your full name'
                        }
                    }
                },}
            }) }); });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you need to fix

1 .You are using name "submit" for your submit button change it

```
<?php
        $data = array(
            'type'=>'submit',
            'class'=>'btn btn-success btn-block',
            'name'=>'save',
            'content'=>'Register',
            'value'=>'submit',
        );

        echo form_button($data); 
    ?>
```

2. Remove extra brackets from your javascript code.

So it will look like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#contact_form').bootstrapValidator({
    feedbackIcons: {
      valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
      invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
      validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
      fullname: {
        validators: {
          stringLength: {
            min: 2,
          },
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'Please supply your full name'
          }
        }
      },
    }
  })
});  // remove extra bracket from here
```

Comment: Check your html output in browser by view page source and make sure that the form and button markup is correct and button name should not be submit otherwise it will cause problem to call submit() function of your form.

Comment: Cool, enjoy coding